# Error training earth models in R - ForwardPassR

Tags: r

I'm using `caret` to train `earth` models like so:

```
test <- train(Y ~ X1+X2,table.needed,method = "earth")
```

which worked fine previously. However, now I am getting the following error:

```
Error in .C("ForwardPassR", fullset = as.integer(fullset), bx = matrix(0,  : 
"ForwardPassR" not available for .C() for package "earth"
```

This also happens when I call `earth` directly:

```
earth(Y ~ X1+X2,data = table.needed)
```

From other questions, I surmise that this is something with the underlying C - does anyone know how to fix the error and get the package running again?

I've attached the `sessionInfo()` call below:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] randomForest_4.6-12 broom_0.4.2         timekit_0.3.0       readr_1.1.1         hts_5.0            
[6] matrixcalc_1.0-3    Matrix_1.2-9        SparseM_1.77        forecast_8.0        earth_4.5.0        
[11] plotmo_3.3.3        TeachingDemos_2.10  plotrix_3.6-5       doParallel_1.0.10   iterators_1.0.8    
[16] foreach_1.4.3       prophet_0.1.1       Rcpp_0.12.11        zoo_1.8-0           caretEnsemble_2.0.0
[21] caret_6.0-76        ggplot2_2.2.1       lattice_0.20-35     reshape2_1.4.2      dtplyr_0.0.2       
[26] data.table_1.10.4   dplyr_0.5.0        

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyr_0.6.3          psych_1.7.5          assertthat_0.2.0     digest_0.6.12        lmtest_0.9-35       
 [6] R6_2.2.1             plyr_1.8.4           MatrixModels_0.4-1   stats4_3.4.0         rlang_0.1.1         
[11] lazyeval_0.2.0       minqa_1.2.4          car_2.1-4            fracdiff_1.4-2       TTR_0.23-1          
[16] nloptr_1.0.4         splines_3.4.0        lme4_1.1-13          foreign_0.8-68       stringr_1.2.0       
[21] munsell_0.4.3        compiler_3.4.0       rstan_2.15.1         mnormt_1.5-5         mgcv_1.8-17         
[26] nnet_7.3-12          tibble_1.3.3         gridExtra_2.2.1      quadprog_1.5-5       codetools_0.2-15    
[31] MASS_7.3-47          ModelMetrics_1.1.0   grid_3.4.0           nlme_3.1-131         gtable_0.2.0        
[36] DBI_0.6-1            magrittr_1.5         StanHeaders_2.15.0-1 scales_0.4.1         quantmod_0.4-9      
[41] stringi_1.1.5        pbapply_1.3-2        tseries_0.10-41      timeDate_3012.100    xts_0.9-7           
[46] tools_3.4.0          hms_0.3              pbkrtest_0.4-7       inline_0.3.14        colorspace_1.3-2    
[51] quantreg_5.33
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no version information about the *earth* package.
Anyway, I encounter with the same error with earth_4.5.0 and the error disappears when I update it to earth_4.5.1. 
So I suggest you update or reinstall the package.